# Parallel processing of two object of same class MRO

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

If we have two object of same class that runs parallel to each other

```
 object1 // runs on processor 1
  object2 // runs on processor 2
```

In C# class objects have it's own set data members and share same set of functions.

***How compiler will allocate methods to class objects if both class want to execute same method at same time.***

```
object1.process();
object2.process();
```

***How compiler will decide priorities of same class objects at run time***

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to effectively answer the question.  If we can assume that that class doesn't share properties or fields (statically) and there's nothing elsewhere being shared, then there's no problems at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand the question... Methods are code. They are bytes like data members but you can be sure those bytes do not change. So there is no issue with "allocation", the code can be executed on any thread at all times without the risc of data corruption.

Indirectly however the method's code may access data members. And you will have so make sure those members will not be changed in an interleaved manner by the different threads.

You can do this in a number of ways which I am sure will be documented all over the net (check re-entrancy, locking, semaphores, mutexes and atomic operations).

Comment: "without the risc of data corruption", was that [a pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing)?

Comment: No pun... Should I have said code corruption instead or do you mean that executing any code may always corrupt data?

Comment: I see the link to RISC now. No, I might as well have used the word "chance".